# Droping rows in DataFrame based on Timestamp Hour

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I'm attempting to drop rows in a DataFrame that has a datetime index column. I'm getting an error for comparing a str to an int using <.

The code I'm running is below.

```
def clean(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        hour = pd.Timestamp(df.index[i]).hour
        minute = pd.Timestamp(df.index[i]).minute
        if hour < 8 and minute < 45:
            df.drop(axis=1, index=i, inplace=True)
```

Which results in the error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

If I write a separate line: `type(pd.Timestamp(df.index[i]).hour)` it returns `<class 'int'>`

I can perform math like `hour += 1` but when comparing the hour or minute the if statement returns the error. Changing the code to `hour = int(pd.Timestamp(df.index[i]).hour)` also doesn't help.

Thank you

Comment: `df = df[(df.index.hour >=8) | (df.index.minute >= 45)]`?

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over the rows (which is gonna be slow), you can just make a mask specifying which rows you want to keep and let `pandas` give you a (faster) answer:

```
df = df[(df.index.hour >=8) | (df.index.minute >= 45)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! For anyone else that finds this thread. I also had a problem of not setting my index to a datetime index properly.